# "Value used here after move" after unpacking account data

Tags: rust, solana

In solana after I iterate over the account I want to get the data of `stake_info` account and modify it.

```
let accounts_iter = &mut accounts.iter();
let stake_info = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
let stake_info_account_data = StakeAccount::unpack_from_slice(&stake_info.data.borrow());

if stake_info_account_data.is_ok(){
        let difference = amount - stake_info_account_data?.amount;

        stake_info_account_data?.amount = amount;
        stake_info_account_data?.rewards_collected = stake_info_account_data?.rewards_collected + (((clock.unix_timestamp as u64 - stake_info_account_data?.timestamp)/stake_info_account_data?.rewards_timeframe) * stake_info_account_data?.rewards_percentage as u64);
        stake_info_account_data?.timestamp = clock.unix_timestamp as u64;

        stake_info_account_data?.pack_into_slice(&mut &mut stake_info.data.borrow_mut()[..]);
```

I'm getting this error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `stake_info_account_data`
    --> src/processor.rs:1052:17
     |
1028 |         let stake_info_account_data = StakeAccount::unpack_from_slice(&stake_info.data.borrow());
     |             ----------------------- move occurs because `stake_info_account_data` has type `Result<StakeAccount, ProgramError>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
1031 |             let difference = amount - stake_info_account_data?.amount;
     |                                       ------------------------ `stake_info_account_data` moved due to this method call
...
1052 |                 stake_info_account_data?.amount = amount;
     |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value used here after move
     |
note: this function takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `stake_info_account_data`
    --> /Users/fanitrade/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/ops/try_trait.rs:218:15
     |
218  |     fn branch(self) -> ControlFlow<Self::Residual, Self::Output>;
     |               ^^^^

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `stake_info_account_data`
    --> src/processor.rs:1053:17
     |
1028 | ...et stake_info_account_data = StakeAccount::unpack_from_slice(&stake_info.data.borrow());
     |       ----------------------- move occurs because `stake_info_account_data` has type `Result<StakeAccount, ProgramError>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
1053 | ...       stake_info_account_data?.rewards_collected = stake_info_account_data?.rewards_collected + (((clock.unix_timestamp as u64 - stake_info_account_data?.timestamp)/stake_info_account_data?.rewards_timeframe) * stake_info_account_data?.re...
     |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value used here after move                                                                                                                                                           ------------------------ `stake_info_account_data` moved due to this method call

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `stake_info_account_data`
    --> src/processor.rs:1053:62
     |
1028 |         let stake_info_account_data = StakeAccount::unpack_from_slice(&stake_info.data.borrow());
     |             ----------------------- move occurs because `stake_info_account_data` has type `Result<StakeAccount, ProgramError>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
1052 |                 stake_info_account_data?.amount = amount;
     |                 ------------------------ `stake_info_account_data` moved due to this method call
1053 |                 stake_info_account_data?.rewards_collected = stake_info_account_data?.rewards_collected + (((clock.unix_timestamp as u64 ...
     |                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value used here after move

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `stake_info_account_data`
    --> src/processor.rs:1053:140
     |
1028 | ...et stake_info_account_data = StakeAccount::unpack_from_slice(&stake_info.data.borrow());
     |       ----------------------- move occurs because `stake_info_account_data` has type `Result<StakeAccount, ProgramError>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
1053 | ...       stake_info_account_data?.rewards_collected = stake_info_account_data?.rewards_collected + (((clock.unix_timestamp as u64 - stake_info_account_data?.t...
     |                                                        ------------------------                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value used here after move
     |                                                        |
     |                                                        `stake_info_account_data` moved due to this method call

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `stake_info_account_data`
    --> src/processor.rs:1053:176
     |
1028 | ...et stake_info_account_data = StakeAccount::unpack_from_slice(&stake_info.data.borrow());
     |       ----------------------- move occurs because `stake_info_account_data` has type `Result<StakeAccount, ProgramError>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
1053 | ...       stake_info_account_data?.rewards_collected = stake_info_account_data?.rewards_collected + (((clock.unix_timestamp as u64 - stake_info_account_data?.timestamp)/stake_info_account_data?.r...
     |                                                                                                                                      ------------------------            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value used here after move
     |                                                                                                                                      |
     |                                                                                                                                      `stake_info_account_data` moved due to this method call

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `stake_info_account_data`
    --> src/processor.rs:1053:222
     |
1028 | ...et stake_info_account_data = StakeAccount::unpack_from_slice(&stake_info.data.borrow());
     |       ----------------------- move occurs because `stake_info_account_data` has type `Result<StakeAccount, ProgramError>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
1053 | ...       stake_info_account_data?.rewards_collected = stake_info_account_data?.rewards_collected + (((clock.unix_timestamp as u64 - stake_info_account_data?.timestamp)/stake_info_account_data?.rewards_timeframe) * stake_info_account_data?.r...
     |                                                                                                                                                                          ------------------------                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value used here after move
     |                                                                                                                                                                          |
     |                                                                                                                                                                          `stake_info_account_data` moved due to this method call

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `stake_info_account_data`
    --> src/processor.rs:1054:17
     |
1028 |         let stake_info_account_data = StakeAccount::unpack_from_slice(&stake_info.data.borrow());
     |             ----------------------- move occurs because `stake_info_account_data` has type `Result<StakeAccount, ProgramError>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
1053 |                 stake_info_account_data?.rewards_collected = stake_info_account_data?.rewards_collected + (((clock.unix_timestamp as u64 ...
     |                 ------------------------ `stake_info_account_data` moved due to this method call
1054 |                 stake_info_account_data?.timestamp = clock.unix_timestamp as u64;
     |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value used here after move

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `stake_info_account_data`
    --> src/processor.rs:1056:17
     |
1028 |         let stake_info_account_data = StakeAccount::unpack_from_slice(&stake_info.data.borrow());
     |             ----------------------- move occurs because `stake_info_account_data` has type `Result<StakeAccount, ProgramError>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
1054 |                 stake_info_account_data?.timestamp = clock.unix_timestamp as u64;
     |                 ------------------------ `stake_info_account_data` moved due to this method call
1055 | 
1056 |                 stake_info_account_data?.pack_into_slice(&mut &mut stake_info.data.borrow_mut()[..]);
     |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value used here after move
```

Here is the `unpack` function:

```
fn unpack_from_slice(input: &[u8]) -> Result<Self, ProgramError> {
    if input.len() != Self::LEN {
        msg!("Data length is less than required");
        return Err(ProgramError::InvalidAccountData.into())
    }
    let input = array_ref![input, 0, StakeAccount::LEN];
    #[allow(clippy::ptr_offset_with_cast)]
    let (
        amount,
        rewards_percentage,
        rewards_collected,
        rewards_timeframe,
        owner,
        timestamp,
        bump_seed,
    ) = array_refs![input, 8, 1, 8, 8, 32, 8, 1];
    Ok(Self {
        amount: u64::from_le_bytes(*amount),
        rewards_percentage: u8::from_le_bytes(*rewards_percentage),
        rewards_collected: u64::from_le_bytes(*rewards_collected),
        rewards_timeframe: u64::from_le_bytes(*rewards_timeframe),
        owner: Pubkey::new_from_array(*owner),
        timestamp: u64::from_le_bytes(*timestamp),
        bump_seed: u8::from_le_bytes(*bump_seed),
    })
}
```

Comment: Could you share a full error, as provided by `cargo build`? It'd be even better if you minimized your code to a minimal reproducible example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - but the full error is essential in understanding the problem in any case.

Comment: Note also that checking for `is_ok` and then using the question mark operator is very strange and can be idiomatically replaced with `if let Some(stake_info_account_data) = stake_info_account_data { ... }`.

Comment: Especially since the `?` operator can only be used once for `stake_info_account_data`, which is the reason for the error.

Comment: Why did you remove part of the code from the question? Now the error message no longer matches the posted code…

Comment: @Jmb the error is still the same.

Comment: The error refers to `let difference = amount - stake_info_account_data?.amount;` but that line is no longer in the posted code.

Comment: @Jmb didn't notice that I added that line back.

Comment: You should study Rust borrow checker and understand the messages, not withstanding repetitive and unnecessary `?` usage.

Answer (score 2):

You should add `?` at the end of this line:

```
let stake_info_account_data = StakeAccount::unpack_from_slice(&stake_info.data.borrow());
```

As a result:

- If the `Result` was `Err`, that `Err` value would be directly returned to the function caller;
- If the `Result` was `Ok`:

  - The `stake_info_account_data` would be holding the actual value you want to use.
  - There would be no need for an `if` with an `is_ok()` call.
  - You wouldn't need to use the `?` multiple times (which is generally wrong).